# Jekyll 3.7.3 | Error: No source of timezone data could be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, jekyll

```
Configuration file: C:/Users/NiKhil GarakaPati/Documents/GitHub/Nikhil- 
Garakapati.github.io/_config.yml
jekyll 3.7.3 | Error:  No source of timezone data could be found.
Please refer to http://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving 
this error.
```

I'm getting this error when installing Jekyll template to my Github page. I tried adding this **timezone: "America/Vancouver"** to my _config.yml file, but oh no use. Then I tried running **gem install tzinfo-data** on my terminal, but didn't work to clear the error.

Can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you're on a Windows machine from the structure of the filepath. The `tzinfo-data` gem is a little picky about working on Windows. Here's the [docs](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors) on how to resolve it.

> If you are using Ruby on Rails and your project was created on Windows, then you may find that there is already a line in your Gemfile like the following:
>
> `gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]`
>
> If you are using a 64-bit version of Ruby on Windows, then add `:x64_mingw` to the list of platforms as follows:
>
> `gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]`

So if you're using a `gemfile` make sure to put that gem in the file.

Comment: More information can see here: https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors